# Websocket always throws Exception and closes in Tomcat on port 8080

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, websocket

I want to use WebSocket in a webapp. I am using Eclipse (Mars.2 Release 4.5.2) to run a Tomcat 7.0.77 instance. It works when deployed to a standalone Tomcat instance, but not when Tomcat runs in Eclipse.

I have also tried Tomcat 8.0.43, with the same results.

In Eclipse, a java.net.SocketException is always thrown when the onMessage method calls the sendText method, with message "Connection reset by peer: socket write error", and the browser's onclose function is called.

I have a basic endpoint:

```
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/echo")
public class EchoServer {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("onOpen: " + session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        System.out.println("onMessage: " + session.getId() + ", " + message);
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        System.out.println("onClose: " + session.getId());
    }
}
```

and a simple test UI:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebSocket test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var Example = {

                socket: undefined,

                open: function() {

                    this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/echo/echo");

                    this.socket.onopen = function() {
                        console.log("onopen");
                    };

                    this.socket.onmessage = function(e) {
                        document.getElementById("message").innerText = e.data;
                    };

                    this.socket.onclose = function() {
                        console.log("onclose");
                    };

                },

                send: function(message) {
                    this.socket.send(message);
                }
            }

            Example.open();

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="message"></div>
        <button onclick="Example.send('Hello world')">Send</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the UI's button is clicked, the message is sent to the endpoint. The endpoint then sends the message back to the UI using `getBasicRemote().sendText(message)`.

Within Eclipse, Tomcat throws the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:286)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.sendCloseMessage(WsSession.java:572)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.doClose(WsSession.java:466)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.onError(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:161)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.access$300(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:47)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onError(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:225)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:208)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:203)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:93)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:635)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.FutureToSendHandler.get(FutureToSendHandler.java:120)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:281)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.BioServletOutputStream.doWrite(BioServletOutputStream.java:38)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletOutputStream.writeInternal(AbstractServletOutputStream.java:153)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletOutputStream.write(AbstractServletOutputStream.java:121)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.onWritePossible(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:94)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doWrite(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:81)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.writeMessagePart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:456)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessage(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:344)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:276)
... 14 more
```

The WebSocket is then immediately closed, and `onClose` is triggered. I am using Chrome 57 and MS Edge 38.

Is this a known Eclipse problem, or is my test code doing something stupid? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

This isn't an Eclipse problem. It occurs in both an Eclipse-contained Tomcat and a standalone Tomcat when they run on port 8080. If I change the port on either (I used 7777) then it works. I've changed the title of this question to reflect this.

**UPDATE**

It looks like this is a firewall/proxy problem that's closing WebSockets on ports 80 and 8080. Sorry, this is a non-issue.

Comment: I have raised [this with the Eclipse team](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515891) in case they can shed some light on it.

Comment: both tomcats run on port 80?

Comment: @user1516873 No, good point. I was running the Eclipse-contained Tomcat on port 8080, and the standalone Tomcat on port 7077. But I've just tried both ports for the standalone Tomcat. It works on port 7077, but fails on port 8080. Odd. Perhaps this isn't related to Eclipse...

Comment: Wow. Just switched to port 7777 for my Eclipse-contained Tomcat and it works. There's something peculiar about using port 8080. I've made sure that nothing else is using that port.

Comment: It looks like proxy issue. Tomcat trying to upgrade connection to websocket, but it already reset. Your code is OK, so it leaves proxy as main suspect.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm using Kaspersky; I haven't had a chance to switch it off yet but ports 80 and 8080 aren't working, but others are. If you post this as the answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Just self-answer it, write exactly which Kaspersky version you are using. I found only that page https://support.kaspersky.ru/9117 In short - Kaspersky acts as proxy and check all requests on ports 80, 81, 82, 83, 1080, 3128, 7900, 8080, 8088, 8888, 11523